# QueryPerformanceCounter throwing incorrect numbers

Tags: c++, timer, 64-bit, performancecounter

I am using QueryPerformanceCounter to measure the time of some functions/operations. It used to give me correct numbers, for instance, I could test Sleep(1000) and it would return a time very close to 1 second. Now, it returns a time very different. I am not sure what the issue is as the code hasn't changed at all. Here is the code:

## Expected Output:

```
duration : 1.000 seconds
```

## Actual Output:

```
duration : 187.988 seconds
```

## Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")


struct Clock{

Clock(){}
virtual ~Clock(){}
void start();
void stop();
long double duration();

LARGE_INTEGER _start, _end, _freq;

};

void Clock::start(){
_start.QuadPart = 0;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&_freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&_start);
}

void Clock::stop(){
QueryPerformanceCounter(&_end);
}

long double Clock::duration(){
//microseconds
LARGE_INTEGER delta;
delta.QuadPart = (_end.QuadPart - _start.QuadPart) * 1000000;
long double the_duration = ((long double)delta.QuadPart) / _freq.QuadPart;
std::cout << "duration : " << the_duration << " seconds" << std::endl;
return the_duration;
}





void main(){

Clock clock;

clock.start();
Sleep(1000);
clock.stop();
clock.duration();

std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: An eternal question of timing - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0097/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the frequency from the performance counter is exactly 1000000 Hz.

You need to call [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905.aspx) instead, as the frequency can vary (some kernels use the motherboard's 1.024 MHz timer, others use the CPUs time-stamp-counter, which runs at approximately the CPU's clock frequency).

Comment: Also keep in mind that QPC is less useful in modern hardware than it used to be in the past.  It is known to not work as well with modern multi-core CPUs or with modern Windows versions that dynamically throttle the CPU frequency (despite what [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx)). Yes, QPC "works", but it is possible, even likely, that you will get varied/incorrect results at times.

Comment: Thanks Remy - I now used `QueryPerformanceFrequency(&_freq)` and got rid of the `*1000000` and the result returns `1.00007 seconds.` If QPC/QPF are not the best, what would you recommend? Could you direct me towards some literature or discussion on this board regarding a better alternative?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: True--though it's fairly unusual, once in a while I've even managed to get an end time that preceded the start time.

Comment: @Chewco: Unfortunately, there isn't a lot better alternative, at least for really high precising timing. QPC isn't as good as you'd like, but it's still about the best that's available.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yeah, I was pretty pleased with this solution. I even had it in my mind that the `0.00007` error from `Sleep(1000)` was due to std::cout taking extra time to execute. Maybe I will see problems with QPC during more complex applications than my example above.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: with care, and in situations where there's no suspends or dynamic CPU speed tuning at play, direct use of RDTSCP may be better, but you have to either set thread affinity to a single core or do some cross-core calibration and accept an error window when comparing cross-core samples.

Comment: @Chewco: Sleep on Windows is sufficiently imprecise that you can't expect much better accuracy than that under even the best circumstances (it normally does scheduling in increments of around 10 ms, so anything finer than that is pretty much pure luck).

Comment: @Chewco: in my testing, QPC often falls back on RDTSC and doesn't work reliably when samples are taken on different cores, so the issue is with the system load forcing movement of your threads across cores, and the mis-sync of TSC registers between cores, which MS says the HAL - Hardware Abstraction Layer in the BIOS - is responsible for - not a very helpful position.  (MS claims this is improved under Win7 but I don't believe it).

Comment: @TonyD: I do believe it. Although it's not perfect (by any means) under Windows 7, it was substantially worse under Vista. One problem is that Windows tends to move threads between cores a lot more than really necessary (which I guess is supposed to be reduced in Windows 8, but I haven't really tested it enough to say with certainty).

Comment: I am now reading up on RDTSCP. Btw: I am on a Windows 8 (VC++ 2013) for my personal PC.

Comment: @Chewco: RDTSCP automatically serializes, where RDTSC requires manual serialization (usually by calling CPUID). Assuming current hardware and software, it's usually pretty much the same as QPC.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: another very nice feature of RDTSCP is that it can tell you the core id (assuming the OS stores it in `TSC_AUX` which Windows does) - that facilitates and speeds reliable use of cross-core calibration data.

Comment: On Windows 7 and perhaps Windows 8, QPC uses a high speed timer that runs around 3 mhz (at least on some Intel motherboards, as opposed using the cpu time stamp counter that runs around 3 to 4 ghz (depending on the cpu).

Comment: We lock each thread to one core with thread affinity to get good timing results.

Answer (score 0):

I use it in VBA. Sometimes I get 8976543566 ms instead of 40
I deal with it by calling it twice in the beginning of procedure:

If gbolShowRunTime = True Then

QueryPerformanceCounter curFrequencyStartLoop

End If

If gbolShowBFTime = True Then

QueryPerformanceCounter curFrequencyEndLoop    'Get the end time

QueryPerformanceCounter curFrequencyStartLoop ' reseed it

End If

Thereafter it works fine.

Comment: As the other answer states, it is not enough to call `QueryPerformanceCounter()` by itself, you also need to call `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` as well